# mysql-python error on django 1.7, python 3.4: Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe'

Tags: python, mysql, django, visual-studio-2013

When I am installing `MySQL-Python` on `Django 1.7`, `Python 3.4`,

**Error :**

```
Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to install this package.  What's missing in the `cl.exe`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When does the error happen? And why is Microsoft Visual Studio part of this django stack?

Comment: I am using the Django virtual environment in Visual Studio. I got this message when I tried to install mysql-python with installing python package.

Comment: I see. You should probably add a visual-studio tag to the question.

Comment: It's not a Visual Studio question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install the library from source. Download zip file from [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5), unzip it, open command line and cd into it and run :

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install the lib into your Python site-packages folder.

Comment: It raises the same error message. Anyway, thanks to both of you.

Comment: Try installing via pip... this kind of error comes when some dependency packages are missing for intended package, pip generally install all such libs along with the main package.